# Spacing between HTML HEADINGS

Tags: php, html, css

How can i manage the SPACE between two HTML headings without using EXTERNAL CSS.
i want to use INLINE CSS or any HTML TAG.
I have googled a lot, but i am not able to find appropriate solution.
Kindly Help

Comment: I am searching for the appropriate INLINE CSS code, but unable to find any, i want to know, if any INLINE code for the same EXISTS or NOT

Comment: Any CSS you can put into an external stylesheet works equally well in an inline `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You didin't say which heading you're using,but here's an example using a h1 and a h2 heading:

```
<h1 style="margin-bottom:50px">This is a H1 heading</h1>
<h2>This is a H2 heading that is a bit away from the H1 heading</h2>
```

Comment: It wont help, as i want to reduce the HEIGHT between the HEADINGS, at 0px, it will be normal height.

Comment: Could you explain? I don't get it. Maybe a screenshot of your problem or a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by height. Lucas T is showing you the spacing between two header tags. The space between them is controlled by a number of things. Assuming they are within the same piece of scaffolding then line-height, padding, margin and display will be the places to check first but almost every property can affect how 2 elements sit next to each other.